# Binding Knockout To JXQUERY GRID

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to integrate and bind knockout observable array to my jxquery grid.  Also when I click my search button it refreshes my grid.  The code I have below is not binding my observable array to my grid on load or after search

js

```
  var initialData = [
    { username: "test", transdate: "test2" },
    ];


    var self = this;

    self.reportTitle = ko.observable();

    self.selectedUser = ko.observable();

    self.startDate = ko.observable();

    self.endDate = ko.observable();

    self.users = ko.observableArray();

    self.results = ko.observableArray(initialData);


    function initialize() {

        dataModel.getUsers()
          .success(function (data) {
              $.each(data, function () {
                  var obj = { id: this._id, username: this.username }
                  self.users.push(obj);
              })
          }).fail(function () {
              self.errors.push("An unknown error occurred.");
          });
    };

    initialize();

    self.errors = ko.observableArray();

    self.search = function () {
        dataModel.getCompoundLog(self.selectedUser(), self.startDate(), self.endDate()).success(function (data) {
            $.each(data, function () {
                var obj = { username: this.user.username, transdate: this.transdate }
                self.results.push(obj);
            }) 
        }).fail(function () {
            self.errors.push("An unknown error occurred.");
        });
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata');
    }



}


app.addViewModel({
    name: "Report",
    bindingMemberName: "report",
    factory: ReportViewModel
});
```

view

```
<div data-bind="jqxGrid: {source: results, autoheight: true,
                columns: [
                    { text: 'username', dataField: 'username', width: 200 },
                    { text: 'transdate', dataField: 'transdate', width: 200, cellsalign: 'right' },
                ]}" id="jqxgrid"></div>
```

Comment: Are you missing applyBindings call or are you doing it somewhere else?

Comment: I would also suggest doing all the coding in your vm, not in the data-bind tag, and then use a custom binding to apply the settings to the element

Comment: also pretty sure jqxGrid isn't a knockout bindable... do you mean to use data-bind="attr: {"jqxGrid": {....}} "http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html

Comment: This is a single page app so my bindings are happening in another js fileb @Krishna Teja Veeramachaneni.

Comment: @QBBM5 Can you be more specific maybe give me an example what you mean

Comment: @MichaelCrook i tried the attr still didnt work I found that example somewhere where they were able to bind the grid like I have above

Comment: @Adam Looking at the jqwidget grid with knockout example, the code you have provided seems alright. So, the issue might be else where. Couple things you can try 1) Right below the jqgrid, add a table and try to print the results collection and its properties and see if you see anything. If you can, that means the bindings are working fine.(There is a chrome extension which helps with Knockout bindings..search in chrome store). 2)If the bindings are not working, you know what to fix.3) I dont see the rest of code, make sure you used all the required styles like <div id='jqxWidget'>, etc

Comment: @KrishnaTejaVeeramachaneni  the table does display so the bindings are good, Ill double check make sure i have everything